# Cordova 3.5.1 with iOS 8 device, remote debugging on Safari 7.1

Tags: ios8, cordova-3, safari7

I've exported an ad hoc distribution of a Cordova app for testing purpose. After installing the OTA on an iPad with iOS 8 and connecting it to the mac, it's not possibile to use remote debugging of Safari, it simply doesn't show the app in Developer menu.

Is there a solution for this or an alternative to Safari for remote debugging on iOS device?

**edit:**
Updating Safari to 7.1 also broke web inspector on ad hoc distribution on iOS 7 devices, before the update it worked, anyone having the same issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked and Safari iOS 8 remote debugging works with latest nightly build

you can grab one here http://nightly.webkit.org/

Edit

Looks like Safari 7.1 also came out, according to this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6537575 it solves the inspector issues

Comment: I'm already using Safari 7.1, I can debug the app only if running from XCode. If I download the app (ipa) and connect the device, I can't see it in developer menu

Answer (score 1):

i used 
http://debug.build.phonegap.com

include 
http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#yourappname
in your Cordova app code

open
http://debug.build.phonegap.com/client/#yourappname

the script allow remote debugging of your running app on device.

Comment: Thanks @ahul_send89, I will give it a try, but it doesn't really solve my problem with Safari

Comment: u can also install this on your local machine .

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Installing.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEqwnpLYnI0

its almost similar remote debugging  to safari.

Comment: @ahul_send89 I would like to avoid installations on locale machine, but they are helpful alternatives